# Could not cast value of type (class) to (class) Swift3 Class and Interface -

Tags: swift, xcode, interface, swift3

I'm migrating to Swift3,
Got stuck with a framework.

Interesting that I managed to import from Objective C to Swift, had a problem,

defined that,

```
@interface ParentInterface:SomeOtherInterface

class Child: ParentInterface {
    //some code 
}
```

now,

```
 let Child:obj = someClassFunctionReturnsParentClassObject  as! Child
```

The output error is,

```
Could not cast value of type 'ParentInterface' (0x1000d2910) to 'Child' (0x1000d2338).
```

I don't know where I'm wrong.
Thank in advance!

Comment: The question is too vague (too much *some...*) and `let Child:obj` is most likely not intended apart from the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try `let Child:obj = someClassFunctionReturnsParentClassObject as? Child` instead.